# String to date not working in C++ when using the %d%m%y format to create am std::time_t

Tags: c++, string, time

I am trying to get a date from a string, which is a question that's been asked a thousand times before, but for some reason, even though all the examples are the same when I follow them, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
struct std::tm tm;
std::istringstream stringStream("191121");
stringStream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%d%m%y");
std::time_t time = mktime(&tm);
```

I think I am using the correct format, which I found here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags

Even though it is from boost, as far as I know, those flags are pretty standard.

Whenever I run this code, the variable `time` is always -1.

Comment: You should check whether `get_time` succeeds and also what the value of `tm` is before you convert it to `time`. Run something like: `https://www.ideone.com/3o4jCX`

Comment: Fully initializing the `tm` struct did not work. The stringStream.fail() function returns true however, but I'm not sure how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) may only fill in the fields of `tm` which are present in the string (it is unspecified whether implementations set unused fields to zero).

As `tm` is uninitialised this likely leads to an invalid time which causes `mktime` to fail. Initialising `tm` at the start of the code fixes the problem. It's also a good idea to check that stream operations succeed before using their results.

```
std::tm tm{};
std::istringstream stringStream("191121");
stringStream >> std::get_time(&tm, "%d%m%y");
if (!stringStream) {
  throw std::invalid_argument("invalid date string");
}
std::time_t time = mktime(&tm);
```

Comment: Running your code sample throws an invalid_argument exception, yet I am not sure what is causing this. How would you go about investigating the problem?

Comment: @MathieuPoulin what compiler/standard library/os are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2019 (v142) on Windows with the Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 and the ISO C++ 17 Standard.

Comment: This exact code works for me in vs 2019, is this your entire program? Maybe there's something odd about your locale settings?